# Performance analysis of Web Page

Tags: javascript, web-applications, performance-testing, television, hbbtv

I built a Hbbtv Application.

I want to analyze the performance of the app when running on TV.
Since there is no developer tools usage on tv, how do I get the rendering, page loading, blank rate time?

Is it possible to display these using javascript?

Comment: I would suggest the use of a Real User Monitor (RUM) Javascript add in for your pages to provide standard browser metrics for rendering, time to first meaningful paint, etc...  Boomerang is a very popular open source solution in this respect.   You may pair this with the w3c time-taken data in your HTTP logs to match up differences in request time by user agent, as your TV/STB is likely to have a distinct user-agent string you can search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You might add google analytics to your site. Implement device detecting and then if it is TV send performance analysis results (previously implemented performance functions). Functions something like these examples: http://qnimate.com/measuring-web-page-performance-using-modern-javascript-apis/ http://blog.trasatti.it/2012/12/measuring-the-speed-of-resource-loading-with-javascript-and-html5.html , https://trackjs.com/blog/monitoring-javascript-memory/ , https://medium.com/@felipedutratine/frontend-performance-monitoring-in-js-29832051d2ec
2. You should detect TV user agent and then simulate it in Google Chrome Dev Tools (w3c validator also allow do that) and then perform audit test in Google Chrome Dev Tools "Audit" tab.
   Check https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/operating_platform/smart-tv/